# Interpreting p-values in a non-linear model

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value

If I run a multiple linear regression on a dependent variables and some independent variables and my *p*-values turn out to be significant for some independent variable, can I make the conclusion that there is a relation /association between that independent variable and the dependent variable even if the R-squared is low or the residual plot is not normally distributed?

I don't want to use the model to predict the dependent variable, In fact I don't care if the actual relation is linear or non-linear. All I care is to conclude if there is a relation/association (linear or non-linear) between a set of independent variables and the dependent variable. Can I use the *p*-value in the multiple regression for this purpose or should I use another measure?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Note that your response / outcome variable is usually called the *dependent* variable, and the predictor / explanatory variables are called *independent* variables.

Comment: A quick google image search turns up the following image:  http://www.statisticalengineering.com/images/cor2.gif.  This is an example of a tight relationship between x and y that has a correlation of zero.  This sample sort of logic can be extended to multivariate space -- if you have a variable $x$ that has a quadratic relationship with $y$, conditional on other variables $Z$, you'll get a beta near zero, even if there truly is a relationship.

Comment: It looks like you have got two accounts: if you were using your original account you would have been able to edit your question directly, but since you used an alternative account I had to approve your edit for you. If this is the case, please make sure you [merge your accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).